# Why the encoding works in Eclipse but don't outside Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, iso-8859-1

I have a Java application that reads an XML file that may have accents and must create 2 signed XML files that must have the same accent encoded correctly.

The code that writes the XML in the output files is as follows:

```
PrintStream ps1=new PrintStream(fileoutputstream1, true, "ISO-8859-1");
String strdoc=new String(enviodocumentostributarios.getDocument());

ps1.print(strdoc);
ps1.close();
```

The `getDocument` method returns a byte array obtained from a `ByteArrayOutputStream` updated with the following method:

```
public static void getNiceXML(Document doc, OutputStream out, boolean encoding) {
    Format f = Format.getPrettyFormat(); 
    if(encoding)
        f.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    f.setExpandEmptyElements(true);
    f.setLineSeparator("\r\n");
    f.setIndent("\t");
    f.setTextMode(TextMode.NORMALIZE);
    XMLOutputter dout = new XMLOutputter(f);

    dout.output(doc, out);
}
```

The classes `Document`, `Format` and `XMLOutputter` are provided for the `jdom2` library.

If an XML input file has something like this: `<NmbItem>Pañuelo AFECTO</NmbItem>`, when I execute my program from Eclipse, the output files are encoded correctly. However, if I execute my program from command line, the output files have `<NmbItem>PaÃ±uelo AFECTO</NmbItem>`, instead of `<NmbItem>Pañuelo AFECTO</NmbItem>`. I tried even re-encoding the XML content before writing it into the files, with no avail.

Here is the pom.xml for my program:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cl.maraneda</groupId>
    <artifactId>dtesign</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>dtesign</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jabylon</id>
            <name>jabylon</name>
            <url>http://www.jabylon.org/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-security</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gnu.getopt</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-getopt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I tried the following with this pom.xml with no avail:

1. Change the `<project.build.sourceEncoding>` value to ISO-8859-1
2. Modify the `<properties>` tag so it looks like this:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

And add the `<maven-compiler-plugin>`

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.7.0</version>
       <configuration>
           <source>1.7</source>
           <target>1.7</target>
           <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is there something special I must do so the output files may be encoded correctly as with Eclipse?

EDIT:

3. Added maven-resources-plugin. Still no avail:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0</version>
     <configuration>
        <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: did you set project encoding?

Comment: As far as I know, the only encoding properties set are those shown in pom.xml

Comment: Windows' console is weird with encodings. It won't use charset iso-8859-1 unless you configure it to do so and Java doesn't provide a way as the console needing its own charset which is different to the system charset is a stupid concept exclusive to Windows. Why do you care what is displayed in a console? You're writing files, and the files are correct, aren't they?

Comment: This is likely a display problem of the console.

Comment: This is the problem. The output files are OK when my program runs under Eclipse, but if I execute it from any other place, the files have this encoding problem when displayed in an text editor. The console does not display nothing important. The important thing is the output files.